# Time-based profiling using Clang instrumentation

Tags: c++, clang

Clang's `-fprofile-instr-generate` option can record the number of times each line of code (and even parts of a line of code) is executed. There is some overhead but it is pretty minimal.

Is there a way to get Clang to do a similar thing but recording the total execution *time* for a line of code rather than the number of times it was run.

I know there are sample-based profilers (perf, etc.) but these seem to suck - e.g. as far as I can tell they sample the call stack so you don't get line-level information.

I am ok with a significant overhead (e.g. 100%) as long as it doesn't distort the relative timings too much (+/-30% is fine).

Comment: Logging the time with nanosecond resolution for every line sounds like a lot more overhead to me. The register spilling alone will probably give you 10x, the logging will probably bring it to 1000x.

Comment: I think you could do something using performance counters that should be reasonably fast. Anyway I am happy with a large overhead in my code - I expect most of the time to be taken in libraries I am using (e.g. the standard library).

Comment: You could use [`rdtsc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) maybe, which uses two 32-bit registers (`-fprofile-instr-generate` uses one), and is one instruction. Should be very fast. Not measuring time exactly, but I am happy to disable clock scaling etc.

Comment: ...uhm, conceptually speaking, while you can always *count* the number of times a line (=full expression) is logically executed, can you even *define* the *time* needed to execute it ? eg. full expressions instructions can interleave and mix under the as-if rule as per effect of the optimizer; if the instrumentation code inhibits the optimizer you may heavily overestimate the result (eg. autovectorized lines), if it doesn't you get possibly meaningless results ... or am I missing something ?

Comment: That is true, but I'm happy with somewhat distorted results due to disabling out-of-order execution and so on. I know a perfect result isn't really possible.

Answer (score 1):

There does seem to be something like this - it's called [XRay](https://llvm.org/docs/XRay.html) and was developed [by Google](https://research.google.com/pubs/pub45287.html).

It doesn't go as far as line-by-line profiling, or even to the basic block level as far as I can tell. The granularity is limited to functions - but you can control exactly which functions are instrumented (by default those with more than 100 instructions) and even turn on and off the instrumentation at runtime.

It seems to be at a fairly early stage of development and only works on Linux. Looks useful nonetheless.

**Edit**: [gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) actually work very well for this (I guess I dismissed them earlier because `pprof` didn't used to work at all on Mac, but I fixed that). I *strongly* recommend you use the `-http` option of `pprof` - it gives you a cool interactive interface with source code, a call graph, a flame graph and so on.